# set visibility of label inside webmethod c#

Tags: c#, webmethod

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> lfromp(string id)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
        Label lbltxt = (Label)page.FindControl("lbltxt");
    }
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=logistics.jayom.org,1434;Initial Catalog=logistics_kl;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=kl_admin;Password=Admin@2222");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SPlgfpro", con); //select login from profile
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter param;
    param = new SqlParameter("@id", id);
    param.DbType = DbType.String;
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    //dlstprofile.Items.Clear();
    //for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    //{
    //    dlstprofile.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
    //}
    con.Close();
    SqlCommand lfp = new SqlCommand("SPlgfpro");//select class from class
    lfp.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    lfp.Connection = con;
    SqlParameter dpra;
    dpra = new SqlParameter("@id", id);
    dpra.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    dpra.DbType = DbType.String;
    lfp.Parameters.Add(dpra);
    con.Open();
    lfp.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter lda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(lfp);
    DataSet dds1 = new DataSet();
    lda1.Fill(dds1);
    SqlDataReader drlp = lfp.ExecuteReader();
    {
        if (drlp.Read())
        {
            id = drlp["login"].ToString();
        }

        else
        {

            //if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            //{
            //    Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
            //    Label lbltxt = (Label)page.FindControl("lbltxt");
            //    lbltxt.Visible = true;
            //}
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    List<string> emp = new List<string>();
    return emp;
}
```

This is my `cs` page and the code is running properly if i am not using label but I cannot use my label inside my

> [WEBMETHOD]

Here `lbltxt` is My label and i want to set this as visible if my condition is not satisfied

Comment: use java script for visible Lable after success web method

Comment: how to use that can you just show me a demo please

Comment: Your code is returning a list of strings, this method isn't a webforms type call.

Comment: Try `AutoPostBack="True"` in `lbltxt`

Comment: If is you have id of the `lbltxt`. as @AliasgharBahrami told add jquery like below
`$(document).ready(function(){
$('#lbltxt').show();
});`

Comment: I hope that database username and password isn't real. Otherwise I would delete this post.

Comment: @Steve its not real\

Comment: @Thennarasan autopostback on label?

Comment: @AngelPriyanka : Yes

Comment: @Thennarasan I don,t think it will work

Answer (score 0):

Use This Sample

```
function RunWebMethod() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Test.aspx/RunWebMethod",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                 document.getElementById("LableName").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: It's funny how you use jQuery to make the call, but not to hide a part of DOM.

Comment: $(document).ready(
     function () {
        $.ajax(
             {
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "frmbookinghistoryv5.2.aspx/lfromp",
                 data: "{'id':'id','lbltxt':'lbltxt'}",
                 contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                 datatype: "json",
                 async: true,
                 cashe: false,
                 success:function msg()
                 {
                     $(document).ready(function () { $('#lbltxt').show(); });
                 }`

Comment: Check this code and check alert return null or element '$(document).ready( function () { 
$.ajax( { 
type: "POST", url: "frmbookinghistoryv5.2.aspx/lfromp",
 data: "{'id':'id','lbltxt':'lbltxt'}",
 contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
 datatype: "json",
 async: true,
 cashe: false,
 success: function (msg) {
alert($('#lbltxt'));
 $('#lbltxt').show();  }

});'

Comment: ... and try spelling **cache** correctly, not with an s.

Answer (score 0):

```
 static Label lbl=null;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbl = (Label)this.Page.FindControl("lbltxt");
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static List<string> lfromp(string id)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("MYCONNECTIONSTRING");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SPlgfpro", con); //select login from profile
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter param;
            param = new SqlParameter("@id", id);
            param.DbType = DbType.String;
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            //dlstprofile.Items.Clear();
            //for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            //{
            //    dlstprofile.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
            //}
            con.Close();
            SqlCommand lfp = new SqlCommand("SPlgfpro");//select class from class
            lfp.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            lfp.Connection = con;
            SqlParameter dpra;
            dpra = new SqlParameter("@id", id);
            dpra.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            dpra.DbType = DbType.String;
            lfp.Parameters.Add(dpra);
            con.Open();
            lfp.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter lda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(lfp);
            DataSet dds1 = new DataSet();
            lda1.Fill(dds1);
            SqlDataReader drlp = lfp.ExecuteReader();
            {
                if (drlp.Read())
                {
                    id = drlp["login"].ToString();
                }

                else
                {
                    Label l = lbl;
                    l.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: label if failed to visible

Answer (score 0):

```
** now use this code:**
     Label lbl = new Label();
     lbl.Attributes.Add("ID", "id");
     lbl.Text = "";
        if (false)
        {
            lbl.Text = "your Text";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl.Text = "";
        }
```

Comment: showing error on page.findcontrol(the name page doesnot exist in a current context)

Comment: use (Label)this.Page rather than (Label)Page

Comment: keyword this is not valid in static property

Answer (score 0):

WebMethod is inside the webservice and you should not be accessing controls inside it. The two are completely seperate stuff for seperate purposes. Whatever be the condition, you should check that on your web page and call your web service accordingly. Mixing web page related code like accessing controls inside a web service is really really bad design.